# Is there some way to install TLS 1.2 certificate over a WebLogic 8.1 Application without migrate the webserver?

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic

I have a very old web application which runs over a BEA Weblogic Server 8.1 with Java 4 (jdk142_11). For the moment we can't migrate to a newer server.. Someone thinks could be a way to install a TLS 1.2 certificate in this application? I know the application is very old...

Thank you for the answer even if the answer is that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration you have provided, its not possible. You need to be on a recent update of JDK 7 or ideally JDK8 and above. Now, you could try and install JDK8 and see if it works with WebLogic 8.1. Keep in mind though that even if it works, Oracle will not support it. Of course, I dont think Oracle will support such an old version of WebLogic anyway :)
A better option is to frontend the application using a load balancer, terminating SSL on the load balancer and configuring the load balancer for TLSv1.2.